# Layout distrubed when using symbol # in my app

Tags: android, button

I created a simple keypad in my app with buttons, which looks as below when i am using # symbol. The red circles shows the layout disturbance.

[image: Layout with # symbol]

If i used any other character in place of # it will look like as below.

[image: Layout with other than # symbol]

Compare above 2 images some disturbance of layout at red colored circles. Please help me regarding this. Why i am getting disturbed layout when using # symbol ? How to solve it ?

Comment: I can't see any images!!

Comment: Try fixing the size of the layouts.

Comment: Each row has linear layout with horizontal orientation and each element in linear layout has layout weight="1", layout width & height are wrap_content.

Comment: you can fix the width of each box with a particular number like
android:layout_width = "70dp"...
i am giving approx size,..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make both `layout_width` and `Layout_height` as `fill_parent` and assign `weigth` to each button. Since it has layout_width as **wrap_content** the problem is arising..

Comment: Thanks for answer, just now i checked same thing.